# Recursively test all flac files in a folder

Tags: recursion, find, flac

I wish to have a command or script that will execute the test feature of flac on all flac files in a folder and its sub-folders. (i.e. $ flac -t music_file.flac)

I've tried using

```
find . -name "*.flac" -exec flac -t '{}' \;
```

and it works, however the flac test function also writes a copyright/warranty output before testing each file, making it difficult to clearly see the result of 'ok'.

I've also tried using

```
for file in 'ls *.flac'
do
  flac -t $file
done
```

which works much neater (only writes the warranty/copyright statement once initially) but does not recursively act on sub-folders.

Could I request some help in improving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the most an elegant solution, but you can use your original command with grep to exclude bits you don't want. So if you wanted the list of files that were tested along with the status, you could search for:

```
find -name "*.flac" -exec flac -t '{}' \; |& grep "\.flac"
```

'&' is important since it seems flac outputs most stuff to stderr.

Comment: This will do the job nicely, now why didn't I think of that!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `--silent`/`-s` to `flac` and it will not include the copyright info, etc., in the output. Note, however, that it will also not show anything when the file *is* ok, only outputting if it is *not* ok.

Comment: Thanks, it is an option I've tried but I would hope to find a solution halfway between silent and default.

Answer (score 1):

I get no credit for this, but I think I found a command [here](https://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2015/03/31/test-flacs-corruption/) which seems to do exactly what the orginal poster wants and which works better for me than the ones proposed here.

```
find -type f -iname '*.flac' -print0 | xargs --null flac -t
```

One quibble with this command is that in the one instance I've tested so far, it processes the files in a seemingly random order. (But the same was true with the commands here.) Also, if there are very many files, I'm not sure it will be easy to spot the errors among all the okays. The author of the command recommends adding -w and -s switches to suppress everything except errors, but that seems to be just what the original poster wants to get away from.

Answer (score 0):

```
-R, --recursive  list subdirectories recursively
```

You can try this:

```
for file in 'ls -R *.flac'
do
    flac -t $file
done
```

Comment: flac: unrecognized option `--recursive' is the output of the -R

Comment: Some more about this one, I've since learned that the "ls" command is actually unnecessary, and it's not acting as the bash command "ls" in this instance. The for loop is already listing all files in the directory, and an "echo" debugging command inside the loop shows that $file is equal to "ls" on the first iteration.